# Java how to respond to HttpExchange

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, httpserver

I am new to Java. I used write server in `Golang`. I need to send response to the `HttpExchange`. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
  Server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000),0);
  Server.createContext("/login", new SimpleHandler());
  Server.setExecutor(null);
  Server.start();
}
class SimpleHandler implements HttpHandler
{
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange request) throws IOException 
    {
     //Here I need to do like request.Response.Write(200,"DONE");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html

Comment: That is the one I was looking for. Thanx!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `sendResponseHeaders(int rCode, long responseLength)` method. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#sendResponseHeaders(int,%20long)) and the example:

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpExchange request) throws IOException {
     request.sendResponseHeaders(200, "DONE");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Handle method in your case should looks like:

```
    public void handle(HttpExchange request) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] response = "DONE".getBytes();
        e.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length);
        OutputStream os = e.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response);
        os.close();
   }
```